# Can I say "They must get something right’" to indicate someone must have made some wise choices?

Tags: meaning, phrases

***Get something right*** is a very frequently used phrase, so I thought it should be some kind of usual usage. But I searched it in COCA, it turns out there are no records. So I wonder if it’s a good way to say someone must have made some smart choices.Or is there any good alternative to that?

Answer (score 2):

It's usually in the past tense, *they got something right* or *they must have gotten something right*.

[image]

Comment: Further to the above, for future events, the form *need to **do** something right* would probably be more common. Also, in contemporary language, preference for future events is more commonly expressed using *need to do* and *have to do* than *must do* (the latter being typical for beliefs about the present, as in "you must be starving").